# Blazor Server App with single-sign on and different user roles per "page"

Tags: authorization, single-sign-on, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, user-roles

I'm building a Blazor Server App that has a database that has already been established with tables/fields. The db has the following tables: users, groups, roles, sitemap and the association tables to go between them to allow a user to have multiple entries in each. The app gets fed the user's ID from an SSO instance and from there will access the db to display the navigation accordingly and as the user goes to each "page" it will allow the user (based on their role/group) to see or do things accordingly. I'm new-ish to Blazor Server but even more-so building the application from the ground up using SSO and a db that must be accommodated as it sits. Any recommendations on how to get this set up?

Answer (score -1):

I know you can set up blazor server application with azure AD credentials login.

there is a way to convert that into a token.

your problem however is quite different.

You should start from implementing a DbContextFactory, which would create your DB and inserting it through DI into your container.

Yu can auto create DB context alternatively with .NET , along with your data table classes. It's pretty cool .

Integrate your Blazor Server app with your SSO provider. This often involves setting up OpenID Connect or OAuth authentication.
You can use ASP.NET Core Identity for user management or adapt it to work with your existing Users, Groups, and Roles tables if they are not already using Identity.

Implement role-based authorization or any custom authorization logic based on your users' roles and groups.
Blazor Server has built-in AuthorizeView components that allow you to show/hide content based on user roles.

Create a navigation menu that dynamically loads items based on the user's role and permissions.
Consider using Blazor components and layouts to build a consistent user interface. Please for gods sake use blazors cool feature to create a reusable component wherever possible

Implement any business logic needed for your application. This includes handling user interactions, processing data, and enforcing business rules.

For me, with testing I mostly use b unit in conjunction with moq library - It's pretty slick.

let me know if you'd like any help with implementing any components or logic. Happy to help :)